# Adding an essential oil to WHO Handrub Formulation

Tags: aromatic-compounds, home-experiment, alcohols

I'm not a chemist, so I prefer to ask this question to some people, who definitely have knowledge in that area.

WHO Handrub Formulation is [available here](https://www.who.int/gpsc/5may/Guide_to_Local_Production.pdf).
Ingridients: Ethanol 96%, Hydrogen peroxide 3%, Glycerol 98%, Sterile distilled or boiled cold water.

I would like to use it to produce 4l of handrub (I have 92% alcohol, and I re-calculated needed amounts).
Can I also add some essential oil to the formula? Only few drops or more ~10 ml?

For example:

- Orange, ingridients: citrus aurantium dulcis peel oil expressed, linalool, citral
- Spruce, ingridients: limonane, linalool, geraniol. INCI: oleum picea excelsa
- Pine, ingridients/INCI: oleum phus silvestris
- Lavender, ingridients/INCI: lavandula angustifolia oil, linalool, limonene

I just want to make sure that the final substance wouldn't be irritating to the hands nor cause any allergies etc. I also found [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/334275803_Improvement_of_the_Efficacy_an_WHO_Alcohol-based_Hand_Rub_Formulation_by_Reducing_Isopropanol_Content_and_Associating_Syzygium_aromarticum_and_Piper_nigrum_Essential_Oils), where they added Piper nigrum Essential Oils to the formula.

Thank you for suggestions.

Comment: I don't see why not. The bulk of the solution is aqueous ethanol so the concentration of the oils is pretty low. As for allergic reactions you are far more likely to suffer one from handing the neat oils and getting a drop of your skin than using the solution

Comment: This is a great example of a well-formatted question about homemade sanitizers. Well done!